# redrawing plots dynamically in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny

I went a totally different direction in this project -- the issue I have is down at the end I need to clear out the graph when a different variable is selected. The graph as it is stays the same. Thanks.

I am not even sure how this would be phrased in the documents -- rewriting graphs, dynamic plotting ???  I saw display.removePlot(display.activePlotIndex()) but am not sure about that -- what do I look up to figure this out?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
oboler_data <- read_csv(file = "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ref.csv")
rdate <- as.Date(oboler_data$DATE,"%m/%d/%y")

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("dataset", "choose a dataset", c("oboler_data")),
        selectInput("column", "Type of Transaction", "placeholder1"),
        selectInput("level", "select level", "placeholder2")
    ),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("table"), plotOutput("Histo"))

))

server <- function(input, output, session){
    dataset <- reactive({
        get(input$dataset)
    })

    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, "column", choices = names(dataset()))
    })

    observeEvent(input$column, {
        column_levels <- as.character(sort(unique(
            dataset()[[input$column]]
        )))
        updateSelectInput(session, "level", choices = column_levels)
    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
        subset(dataset(), dataset()[[input$column]] == input$level)
    })
    DF <- data.frame(Name = LETTERS[1:10], Value = rnorm(20), Value2 = runif(20))
    output$TableOut <- renderDataTable({
        DF
    })
    output$Histo <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(DF, aes(Value)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1,
                                                fill = "blue", color = "white")
    })




}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `req`, as it precludes (and clears!) rendering of a plot if conditions are not met.

```r
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    checkboxInput("cb", "Plot?"),
    sliderInput("cyls", "Cylinders", min = 1, max = 8, value = 4, step = 1),
    plotOutput("plt")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$plt <- renderPlot({
      req(input$cb, input$cyls)
      ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$cyl >= input$cyls,,drop = FALSE],
             aes(disp, mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
        geom_point()
    })
  }
)
```

[image: ggplot2 conditional plot with req function]

The three screenshots above are in sequence: start with "Plot?" deselected, no plot shown; select it, plot appears; deselect it, existing plot disappears.

The way you adapt this to you is to replace the `req(input$cb)` with something that matches your condition of "clear the plot". (I also included `input$cyls` here just to prevent larger more-complex apps from reaching the plot block before all inputs have stabilized. Perhaps not required in most apps, but it's a defensive move that carries little consequence if it is overkill, but lots of benefit when it is needed.)

A slight modification on a theme, "telling the user why the plot disappeared". Replace the `req` with a `validate` and at least one `need`:

```r
      # req(input$cb, input$cyls)
      validate(
        need(input$cb, "You deselected \"Plot!\"")
      )
```

[image: tell the user why]

Comment: Unfortunately req as suggested doesn't help. It does turn the plot on and off but doesn't update the plot  output$Histo <- renderPlot({
        req(input$cb,input$column)
        ggplot(DF, aes(Value)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1,
                                                fill = "blue", color = "white")
    })

Comment: Given the logic of your code, there is no reason for the plot to "clear": when a new variable is selected, the plot is updated. Is it that your plot generation takes too long, and you want it to immediately "blank" while a new plot is calculating/rendering?

Comment: As I said req doesn't work - it will not replot. Also dataframe takes the items from the csv file randomly or not at all - it seemly doesn't import all the data from the csv file. I am missing all sorts of row data on a random basis.  Back to watching more videos I guess  DF <- data.frame(Name = LETTERS[1:10], Value = rnorm(20), Value2 = runif(20))
    output$TableOut <- renderDataTable({
        DF

Comment: On further inspection, with your code, the plot is dependent only on `DF` (which is static data), not on the reactive data. Why would the plot change?

Comment: I actually got this to work. The issue I will now have to deal with is getting the right axis labels and values. I have count on the Y and date on the X. But it's doing a decimal on the Y and the count on the X. Obviously I have more to learn about ggplot  --ggplot(DF, aes_string(x="varY"()))+
            geom_density(colour="darkblue",fill="lightblue")+
            labs(X="DATE",y="Number of transactions",title = paste0(" ",varY()))+
            
            theme_minimal()